# RemoveRange not deleting all records

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following method should delete all old data however, when I did my investigation I found out that some of the data in the database was not delete even though the posted date was within the range. Can someone explain why?

Data That did not get deleted:

19/02/2020
01/04/2020
24/03/2020

```
 public ActionResult DeleteOldData()
    {
        for(int i = 8; i < 900; i++)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            var time = now.AddDays(-i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();
            db.Data.RemoveRange(db.Data.Where(a => a.PostedDate == time).ToList());
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: is PostedDate a string?

Comment: @JerdineSabio yes its string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferrable comparison operator for this one is just comparing the 2 dates with `<=` but the dilemma is you're storing the date as a string, hence we can't compare it directly using LINQ, need to do a workaround like below;

Try the code below, **try it also without the loop**;

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var time = now.AddDays(-i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").ToString();

var dateList = db.Data.ToList();
List<Data> toDelete = new List<Data>();

foreach(var item in dateList){
    if(Convert.ToDateTime(a.PostedDate) <= Convert.ToDateTime(time)){
        toDelete.Add(item);
    }
}

db.Data.RemoveRange(toDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: but I am comparing against a date without time

Comment: @Moe the time will be defaulted to `00:00` for all the records.

Comment: @MOe I updated the answer; `Convert.ToDateTime(a.PostedDate) <= Convert.ToDateTime(time)` corrected the 2nd operand